# Intersection of mapped types

Tags: typescript, mixins

Consider the following:

```
type Properties = {
    foo: { n: number };
    bar: { s: string };
    baz: { b: boolean };
};

declare function retrieveValues<K extends keyof Properties>(add?: K[]): Pick<Properties, K>[K];

// what happens
const x: { n: number } | { s: string } = retrieveValues(['foo', 'bar']);

// what I'm really trying to express (type error)
const y: { n: number } & { s: string } = retrieveValues(['foo', 'bar']);
```

Is there a way to get an intersection of the properties of `Pick<Properties, K>`? Or just a different way to get the intersection of a set of types based on the presence of relevant strings in an array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and [type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) it is possible to transform `{ n: number } | { s: string }` directly into `{ n: number } & { s: string }`.

```
type GetKeys<U> = U extends Record<infer K, any> ? K : never

type UnionToIntersection<U extends object> = {
   [K in GetKeys<U>]: U extends Record<K, infer T> ? T : never
}

type Transformed = UnionToIntersection<{ a: string } | { b: number }>
// Transformed has type {a: string, b: number}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwGkIgM4B4CqA+KBeKGUEAHsBAHYAmKUAShAMYD2ATpWgJbkBmELUCADRQAhuRA4A-AKgAuKOQgA3PgChVoSAXIcm5ACpMAkuTIsUjYLvKYipCtShMARgCtLOfAG9VUPwG0EKC5YeCRUTCwAXXlCEjIqGnpmNjQhYJ4+KH0pbLkFZTUAX3VNaH0WMRRuVgBbCEo8bWtDEzMLBis9NC9ReRRgFi4AcygiqAAfKF7neXIAV1rnLKKsVSA)

The reason this works is basically because conditional types are distributed over union types. From the [conditional types pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316):

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.

Comment: Recent TS type features are designed in a way they can be used as primitives to build a wide array of type transformations (instead of "hard-coding" those transformations into the language)

Comment: Great example of conditional types and infer operator. This should be the top answer for TS >= 2.8.

Comment: @KPD Can you explain to me why if I change `[K in GetKeys<U>]` into `[K in keyof U]` it does not work the same way anymore? I guess it is because in the instantiation of the `GetKeys<U>` there is a conditional type expression, so it distributes into `UnionToIntersection` somehow, but I cannot figure out exactly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Daniel Because the plain `keyof` operator will only include keys that exist in every branch of the union. The `GetKeys` type in this answer gets keys that exist in any branch of the union. A quick example: `keyof ({a: any} | {b: any})` is `never` (because there are no keys that exist in both branches of the union), but `GetKeys<{a: any} | {b: any}>` is `'a' | 'b'`.

Comment: Great answer! Wish they would have a less obscure/more direct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: this answer was originally written before [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) were introduced into the language.  For newer versions of TypeScript, you can indeed [transform arbitrary unions into intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

declare function retrieveValues<K extends keyof Properties>(
    add?: K[]): UnionToIntersection<Properties[K]>;

const x = retrieveValues(['foo', 'bar']);
/* const x: {
    n: number;
} & {
    s: string;
} */
```

Or you could write something specifically to merge the properties that are picked from a type:

```
type PickMerge<T, K extends keyof T> =
    { [P in K]: { [Q in keyof T[P]]: [Q, T[P][Q]] }[keyof T[P]] }[K] extends infer U ?
    [U] extends [[PropertyKey, any]] ? { [KV in U as KV[0]]: KV[1] } : never : never

declare function retrieveValues<K extends keyof Properties>(
    add?: K[]): PickMerge<Properties, K>;

const x = retrieveValues(['foo', 'bar']);
/* const x: {
    n: number;
    s: string;
} */
```

More explanation upon request.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKJqAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJR0aANyQJeUWXAhK8Crj36sWMqAjgAzPFAwLay1bwUSMGqFp2569UJCgAFXCRIXFIIAVooAG9GZnMkJFlIt00AVwBbACMrAF8AbhimDMFcRKh8WXxgXDMAcyg8gqgigC9SjNkM+IAbCGF6-Ib6XmIu4uhzFLgSMihcCCqEbQgANUEulLDyAGkObgg+AUkIECRzf0Dg0PwqFkbBXl4xWS2AbQBdOVl4MnQsHAJiKQUOQAkE8FcXls3lR8vQiChKlBOHRZvNqktVuswiwXgByOJIXEAGiguKKuFxH3yAHoAFRQeFwRGcRKNOCpTJ4AZQABkUUa5TKCzgNW5tOpXm84GgfgQREkAFk8DUIORUCSdvp9oYjiczqgaAxmFEoC8-KY4FAoaUXgBFC1QXWnKCoM1vN6yO0k11+N52931F5O-Vut6BqG7AwCMyWXCwcSNF4wMNag6ms0XcEgLbHEnCEABiRJSHLB3sQQCLbLF4ABndz2rAEYw9lXO4rJolp4hiMxlAJlMgZa5gsMWsNvgAEzbSPaw7HZ2gy6La63Y33R7Pd6ffxyxXK1VL8ErjUwryMxGiCIj9E6TETyc4-HxYmk8mUuQ0+kX4BQECs412TcdIslwfJjUFSpqhFMUJUlIA)

---

TS 2.7- answer:

There's no straightforward type operator which, say, turns a union into an intersection, or allows you to [iterate union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) and do stuff programmatically with the pieces.  So on the face of it you're stuck.

Backing up, if you allow yourself to build `Properties` from pieces instead of trying to break the pieces apart, you can do this:

```
type InnerProperties = {
  n: number;
  s: string;
  b: boolean;
}

type OuterProperties = {
  foo: "n";
  bar: "s";
  baz: "b";
}
```

You can see how each key in `OuterProperties` is a mapping to a key in `InnerProperties`.  (Note that in your `Properties`, each outer property had a single inner property.  You aren't restricted to that, though. If you wanted, say, the `"foo"` outer key to correspond to something with multiple inner properties like `{n: number, r: RegExp}` then you would add `r: RegExp` to `InnerProperties` and put `foo: "n"|"r"` in `OuterProperties`.)

Now you can pick out partial properties like this:

```
type PickProps<P extends keyof OuterProperties = keyof OuterProperties> = {
  [K in OuterProperties[P]]: InnerProperties[K];
}
```

So `PickProps<"foo">` is `{n: number}`, and `PickProps<"bar">` is `{s: string}`, and `PickProps<"baz">` is `{b: boolean}`.  And notice that `PickProps<"foo"|"bar">` is `{n: number; s: string}`, so we have the output type of `retrieveValues()` ready.  We still have to define `Properties` in terms of `InnerProperties` and `OuterProperties`, like this:

```
type Properties = {
  [K in keyof OuterProperties]: PickProps<K>
}
```

And finally you can declare that function the way you want it:

```
declare function retrieveValues<K extends keyof Properties>(add?: K[]): PickProps<K>;
const y: { n: number } & { s: string } = retrieveValues(['foo', 'bar']);
```

So that works.  Hope that's helpful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get the full set of all possible keys and values in a union, use

```
type Intersect<T> =
    (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends
    (x: infer R) => any ? R : never
type ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T, TKey extends keyof Intersect<T> = keyof Intersect<T>> = T extends Record<TKey, any> ? ({
    [P in TKey]: T extends Record<P, any> ? (k: T[P]) => void : never
}[TKey] extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never) : never;
type Usage = { [K in keyof Intersect<TA1>]: ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<TA1, K> };
```