# Type map returning the intersection of the type mapped member of a union

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following data types in my type safe query builder.

```
// types
type SUDI = S | U | D | I
type SUD = S | U | D
type S = 'Select'
type U = 'Update'
type D = 'Delete'
type I = 'Insert'

// states
interface STATE_SUDI { state: 'SUDI' }
interface STATE_SUD { state: 'SUD' }
interface STATE_S { state: 'S' }
interface STATE_U { state: 'U' }
interface STATE_D { state: 'D' }
interface STATE_I { state: 'I' }
```

You can convert between types and states.

```
type TypeToState<T> = 
  SUDI extends T ? STATE_SUDI :
  SUD extends T ? STATE_SUD :
  S extends T ? STATE_S :
  U extends T ? STATE_U :
  D extends T ? STATE_D :
  I extends T ? STATE_I : never;

type StateToType<T> = 
  T extends STATE_SUDI ? SUDI :
  T extends STATE_SUD ? SUD :
  T extends STATE_S ? S :
  T extends STATE_U ? U :
  T extends STATE_D ? D :
  T extends STATE_I ? I : never;
```

The type of an array of states is an array of the union of all state types. For example:

```
declare let array: (STATE_SUDI | STATE_SUD)[]
```

When the type of an array element is mapped with `StateToType`, it becomes:

```
StateToType<STATE_SUDI | STATE_SUD>
// = StateToType<STATE_SUDI> | StateToType<STATE_SUD>
// = SUDI | SUD
// = (S | U | D | I) | (S | U | D)
// = (S | U | D | I)
// = SUDI
```

The behavior I desire is to apply `StateToType` on each member of the union, then get the intersection.

```
BetterStateToType<test>
// = StateToType<STATE_SUDI> & StateToType<STATE_SUD>
// = SUDI & SUD
// = (S | U | D | I) & (S | U | D)
// = (S | U | D)
// = SUD
```

I need help defining `BetterStateToType`.

I know it's possible to convert a union to an intersection, but I cannot figure out if it's also possible to apply the mapping before the intersection.

[Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

[Intersection of mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464913/intersection-of-mapped-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
type BetterStateToType<T> =
  (T extends any ? ((x: [StateToType<T>]) => void) : never) extends
  ((x: [infer I]) => void) ? I : never

type StateToTypeSuSussudio = BetterStateToType<STATE_SUDI | STATE_SUD>;
// = SUDI & SUD
// = (S | U | D | I) & (S | U | D)
// = (S | U | D)
// = SUD
// = "Select" | "Update" | "Delete"
```

It is similar to the regular union-to-intersection code:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

But instead of `U` it uses `[StatetoType<T>]`, which becomes (after distributing the union) something like `[SUDI] | [SUD]`.  The single-element-tuple "box" prevents the compiler from evaluating `SUDI | SUD` which immediately collapses to `SUDI`, while `[SUDI] | [SUD]` is left alone until after the union-to-intersection happens.

And I'm guessing you are okay with the `never`-like result you get with this:

```
type NotSure = BetterStateToType<STATE_S | STATE_U>
// = "Select" & "Update", not gonna happen
```

---

By the way, I tend to avoid using conditional types if I don't have to use them, so I'd be more inclined to define `StateToType<>` like this:

```
type StateTypeMap = {
  SUDI: SUDI
  SUD: SUD
  S: S
  U: U
  D: D
  I: I
}
type StateToType<T extends { state: keyof StateTypeMap }> =
  StateTypeMap[T['state']];
```

which amounts to much the same thing, I suppose.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!