# how get inner key value from a interface

Tags: typescript

Now hava interfae A, want get type B key and value from A.
I don't know how define value of type E.

```
interface A {
    a: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    };
    b: {
        w: boolean;
        h: symbol;
    };
}
```

```
//want
// type B = {
//     name: string;
//     age: number;
//     w: boolean;
//     h: symbol;
// };
```

```
type B<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }[keyof T];
type C<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type D<T> = T extends any ? T[keyof T] : never;
type E<T> = { [K in C<B<T>>]: T[keyof T][K] };
type G = E<A>;
```

Comment: `T[keyof T][K]` has some problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464913/intersection-of-mapped-types)

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279355/1400623

. In your case, `type GetKeys<U> = U extends Record<infer K, any> ? K : never;
type UnionToIntersection<U extends object> = {
   [K in GetKeys<U>]: U extends Record<K, infer T> ? T : never
};

type Wanted = UnionToIntersection<A[keyof A]>
`